# How do you take the user's input and add it to a URL in an iframe?

Tags: html, forms, iframe

I'm trying to make a website that has multiple search engines and compares the results

So far I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>fact checker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="https://www.dogpile.com/search">
        <input type="text" name="q" size="31" value="">
        </form>

        <iframe id="Dogpile"
        title="Dogpile"
        width="1000"
        height="1500"
        src="https://www.dogpile.com">
    </iframe>
</html>
```

I'd like to take the input of form and open the search in the iframe instead of opening it in another page (with the action="https://www.dogpile.com/search")

Can you save the input as a variable with Javascript? Would this work?

```
 input = "https://www.dogpile.com/serp?q=" + input;
```

I'm not planning on putting this online, I'm just doing it for coding practice

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can take input with document.querySelector

```
> let input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

And if you want to add it to form action you can use

```
$('form').on('submit',(el)=>{
   //Here we select currentTarget value(input value)
    let input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]')
   //Here we change action form, .attr() with 1 param you get value of attr, if you 
   //put a second param you set the value of that attribute
   $('form').attr('action',$('form').attr('action')+input)
})
```

What code do on $('form').on() is getting it's value and add input value

https://api.jquery.com/attr/